# Stop hanging synchronous method

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, cancellation

There is a method [HTTP_actions.put_import()](https://github.com/xenserver/xenadmin/blob/master/XenModel/XenAPI/HTTP_actions.cs) in XenAPI, which is synchronous and **it supports cancellation via its delegate**.

I have the following method:

```
private void UploadImage(.., Func<bool> isTaskCancelled)
{
    try
    {
        HTTP_actions.put_import(
            cancellingDelegate: () => isTaskCancelled(),
            ...);
    }
    catch (HTTP.CancelledException exception)
    {
    }
}
```

It so happens that in some cases this method `HTTP_actions.put_import` hangs and doesn't react to `isTaskCancelled()`. In that case the whole application also hangs.

I can run this method in a separate thread and kill it forcefully once I receive cancellation signal, but this method doesn't always hang and **sometimes I want to gracefully cancel this method**. Only when this method is really hanging, I want to kill it myself.

What is the best way to handle such situation?

Comment: If you have a cancellationToken as param of UploadImage, then you can simply call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` inside your method. That will guarantee that exception is thrown from your code on cancellation.

Comment: Best way would be to contact author of this library and ask him to fix this hang (by the way, author of this library reimplemented whole http client functionality from scratch using raw sockets, so no wonder it sometimes hangs).

Comment: I suggest you try out TaskCompletionSource  that is opt provided by microsoft for such type of thing ...you can even read some article based on this

Comment: I have found the code where the hanging happens: https://github.com/xenserver/xenadmin/blob/master/XenModel/XenAPI/HTTP.cs#L307

Comment: Pixar, I have already mentioned that. But not provided the direct link.  I will add that to my answer.

Comment: Hi, I created solution for your issue its working one , please have look and try it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrote blog post for below : http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2017/12/abortcancel-task.html

Tried lot of solution since last 2 hr for you and I come up with below working solution , please have try it out

```
class Program
{
   //capture request running that , which need to be cancel in case
   // it take more time 
    static Thread threadToCancel = null;
    static async Task<string> DoWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        //enable this for your use
    //await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    //{
    //    //Capture the thread
    //    threadToCancel = Thread.CurrentThread;
    //    HTTP_actions.put_import(...); 
    //});
    //tcs.SetResult("Completed");
    //return tcs.Task.Result;

    //comment this whole this is just used for testing 
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Capture the thread
            threadToCancel = Thread.CurrentThread;

            //Simulate work (usually from 3rd party code)
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"value {i}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Task finished!");
        });

        tcs.SetResult("Completed");
        return tcs.Task.Result;
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = source.Token;
        DoWork(token);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested && threadToCancel!=null)
                {
                    threadToCancel.Abort();
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread aborted");
                }
            }
        });
        ///here 1000 can be replace by miliseconds after which you want to 
        // abort thread which calling your long running method 
        source.CancelAfter(1000);
        Console.ReadLine();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is an interesting solution. I will play with it a little bit more =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final implementation (based on Pranay Rana's answer).

```
public class XenImageUploader : IDisposable
{
    public static XenImageUploader Create(Session session, IComponentLogger parentComponentLogger)
    {
        var logger = new ComponentLogger(parentComponentLogger, typeof(XenImageUploader));

        var taskHandler = new XenTaskHandler(
            taskReference: session.RegisterNewTask(UploadTaskName, logger),
            currentSession: session);

        return new XenImageUploader(session, taskHandler, logger);
    }

    private XenImageUploader(Session session, XenTaskHandler xenTaskHandler, IComponentLogger logger)
    {
        _session = session;
        _xenTaskHandler = xenTaskHandler;
        _logger = logger;

        _imageUploadingHasFinishedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(initialState: false);

        _xenApiUploadCancellationReactionTime = new TimeSpan();
    }

    public Maybe<string> Upload(
        string imageFilePath,
        XenStorage destinationStorage,
        ProgressToken progressToken,
        JobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.WriteDebug("Image uploading has started.");

        var imageUploadingThread = new Thread(() =>
            UploadImageOfVirtualMachine(
                imageFilePath: imageFilePath,
                storageReference: destinationStorage.GetReference(),
                isTaskCancelled: () => cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested));

        imageUploadingThread.Start();

        using (new Timer(
            callback: _ => WatchForImageUploadingState(imageUploadingThread, progressToken, cancellationToken),
            state: null,
            dueTime: TimeSpan.Zero,
            period: TaskStatusUpdateTime))
        {
            _imageUploadingHasFinishedEvent.WaitOne(MaxTimeToUploadSvm);
        }

        cancellationToken.PerformCancellationIfRequested();

        return _xenTaskHandler.TaskIsSucceded
            ? new Maybe<string>(((string) _xenTaskHandler.Result).GetOpaqueReferenceFromResult())
            : new Maybe<string>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _imageUploadingHasFinishedEvent.Dispose();
    }

    private void UploadImageOfVirtualMachine(string imageFilePath, XenRef<SR> storageReference, Func<bool> isTaskCancelled)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.WriteDebug("Uploading thread has started.");

            HTTP_actions.put_import(
                progressDelegate: progress => { },
                cancellingDelegate: () => isTaskCancelled(),
                timeout_ms: -1,
                hostname: new Uri(_session.Url).Host,
                proxy: null,
                path: imageFilePath,
                task_id: _xenTaskHandler.TaskReference,
                session_id: _session.uuid,
                restore: false,
                force: false,
                sr_id: storageReference);

            _xenTaskHandler.WaitCompletion();

            _logger.WriteDebug("Uploading thread has finished.");
        }
        catch (HTTP.CancelledException exception)
        {
            _logger.WriteInfo("Image uploading has been cancelled.");
            _logger.WriteInfo(exception.ToDetailedString());
        }

        _imageUploadingHasFinishedEvent.Set();
    }

    private void WatchForImageUploadingState(Thread imageUploadingThread, ProgressToken progressToken, JobCancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        progressToken.Progress = _xenTaskHandler.Progress;

        if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        _xenApiUploadCancellationReactionTime += TaskStatusUpdateTime;

        if (_xenApiUploadCancellationReactionTime >= TimeForXenApiToReactOnCancel)
        {
            _logger.WriteWarning($"XenApi didn't cancel for {_xenApiUploadCancellationReactionTime}.");

            if (imageUploadingThread.IsAlive)
            {
                try
                {
                    _logger.WriteWarning("Trying to forcefully abort uploading thread.");

                    imageUploadingThread.Abort();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    _logger.WriteError(exception.ToDetailedString());
                }
            }

            _imageUploadingHasFinishedEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    private const string UploadTaskName = "Xen image uploading";

    private static readonly TimeSpan TaskStatusUpdateTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    private static readonly TimeSpan TimeForXenApiToReactOnCancel = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    private static readonly TimeSpan MaxTimeToUploadSvm = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

    private readonly Session _session;
    private readonly XenTaskHandler _xenTaskHandler;
    private readonly IComponentLogger _logger;

    private readonly AutoResetEvent _imageUploadingHasFinishedEvent;

    private TimeSpan _xenApiUploadCancellationReactionTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`HTTP_actions.put_import`](https://github.com/xenserver/xenadmin/blob/master/XenModel/XenAPI/HTTP_actions.cs#L59)
calls
[`HTTP_actions.put`](https://github.com/xenserver/xenadmin/blob/master/XenModel/XenAPI/HTTP_actions.cs#L46)
calls
[`HTTP.put`](https://github.com/xenserver/xenadmin/blob/master/XenModel/XenAPI/HTTP.cs#L692)
calls
[`HTTP.CopyStream`](https://github.com/xenserver/xenadmin/blob/master/XenModel/XenAPI/HTTP.cs#L307)

The delegate is passed to `CopyStream` which then checks that the function isn’t null (not passed) or true (return value).  However, it only does this at the `While` statement so the chances are it is the `Read` of the `Stream` that is causing the blocking operation. Though it could also occur in the `progressDelegate` if one is used.

To get around this, put the call to `HTTP.put_import()` inside a task or background thread and then separately check for cancellation or a return from the task/thread.

Interestingly enough, a quick glance at that `CopyStream` code revealed a bug to me.  If the function that works out if a process has been cancelled returns a different value based off some check it is making, you can actually get the loop to exit without generating a `CancelledException()`. The result of the `CancelledException` call should be stored in a local variable.

Comment: Hi, went through you suggestion and created code as in my answer, that is working one